# Changing location in a fiction story with two or more story lines happening at same time

Tags: fiction, plot

In my novel I have many different story lines that are happening at the same time. If I have one scene that takes seven pages and then flips to another scene that actually happened at the same time but in a new location and with different characters, then how do I write the switch without confusing the reader?

Comment: "meanwhile, back at the ranch..." ;)

Answer (score 2):

**At first: Clearly establish the character or location.**
The first time you show new location or POV character, clearly establish both. To do that, focus on two things: **sensory details** (what the character is sensing through the five senses) and **opinions** (what the character thinks of the things being sensed).

The character's opinions will help establish the character.

The first time, **use all five senses.**
These will help establish the location--and to some extent the character:
Of all of the available sensations, *these* are the ones the character is noticing.

**Later: Re-establish the character or location.**
The next time you flip to an already established location or POV character, *remind* the reader by reusing some of the more telling details and opinions. Include a few new details and opinions, to help the reader see what's changed.

**Later: Quickly recall the character or location.**
Later in the story, a quick reminder (recalling one or two evocative details) will be enough, as long as you've clearly established them earlier.

Comment: Also, add some time-stamping or time-orienting elements, like noting that it's the morning, or setting it after an event which the reader knows happened at the beginning of the previous scene.

Comment: In the first scene a preacher is hollering at a girl as she runs across a field. It ends with him being out of breath and exhausted from hollering at her. This is in the first chapter. Then after that 7 page scene ends with the preacher gasping for air it immediately switches to a couple who have just finished having sex and is out of breath looking at the ceiling. Totally different characters and location. How would I make that transition without jolting the reader? It actually is happening at the same time as the preacher is hollering. And, thank you so much for your response.

Comment: I totally get the sensory details etc and have established my characters well. I just need to know how to switch. Do I say, "Meanwhile..." or At that moment...or...across town....? I have many scenes written but do not know how to connect those scenes that take place at the same time in the same chapter.

Comment: One more thing....I read once that you should put *** stars between scenes like this so the reader knows some new location and characters are coming into story. That seems wrong to me so I wanted to see if anyone has a clearer answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, Mark, that's called a scene break. When readers see scene breaks, they typically expect that something has jumped: Time, location, or POV character. So: To indicate a jump in time, location, or POV, add a scene break. Printed books and ebooks represent scene in a variety of ways. For manuscripts, a common way to indicate a scene break is to put a single pound sign on a line by itself. http://www.shunn.net/format/story.html

Comment: Really? Hmm...okay. I appreciate the answer. So I skip a space and put # then skip a space and continue writing in the same chapter right? There are four different story-lines happening throughout the book and most of the time it's at the same time so I guess there would be these # marks throughout and that is acceptable right? Sorry to keep pounding the question but just want to make certain I understand. I appreciate you.

Comment: A challenge with "meanwhile" is that it momentarily pops into the narrator's POV (or the author's). This can work if you've brought the reader to expect a narrator's POV. But if you're usually in a character's head, the "meanwhile" breaks the POV in a more jarring way. Writers who are awesome at transitions can write them so smoothly that they don't always need an explicit scene break. For example, in The Fourth Hand, John Irving sometimes switches POV characters in the middle of a sentence, and does it in a way that you follow from one character's head to another's without the slightest bump.

Comment: Yes, you add a # mark each time you switch storylines. That is perfectly fine in a manuscript. If you publish it, you may want to indicate a scene break in some other way. Take a look at a few of your favorite books for ideas about that.

Comment: @MarkRoss You don't write "meanwhile" if you don't have a POV character telling the story. In your example, you would switch to the couple in bed, and they would talk or cuddle or do whatever, and five pages into *that* scene they would hear the preacher run by their house yelling some of the same dialogue we've already heard. This makes it clear that the previous scene is more or less simultaneous with the current one.

Comment: Lauren, thanks. However, the preacher and the girl he is hollering at are in another state. The couple are talking about going to that location where the preacher was in earlier pages.

Comment: But the preacher/girl do not know the couple.

Comment: You may have to generalize Lauren's excellent advice. Is there *anything* going on that would be known in both places? Anything that might mark the timeframes as being the same? Maybe something that happened on the news just before these scenes, and is on both POV characters' minds. Or a well-known occasion, like a holiday, or an election, or the Dow Jones tanking. It might be ongoing or very recent. It might be in the near future, and the POV characters are anticipating it. Or (perhaps less helpful here) an event observable in both places, such as an eclipse. Anything like that?

Comment: Not really. The preacher is in a town where terrible things happen. The couple have no idea whats ahead for them as they are in bed discussing a trip to this very town.